Linux kernel is not booting up from uboot on x86_64 qemu
I have built uboot and linux for qemu-x86_64 and I am booting u-boot.rom and then try to boot linux from there, but I think cpu resets when I execute zboot command and uboot starts again. Here is my command with which I start qemu:
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1024 -M pc -bios u-boot.rom -drive file=rootfs.ext2.img,format=raw,if=virtio -kernel bzImage -net nic,model=virtio -net user -serial mon:stdio

I have created rootfs.ext2.img as mentioned in the following post create image with partition table in order for uboot to recognize the virtio device.
The main problem is that when I try to boot linux the last message is "Loading bzImage at address 100000 (4820640 bytes)" and then uboot is started again. Here is the log starting from error, I did not put the uboot boot logs twice not to duplicate:
Load address: 0x1000000
Loading: *
TFTP error: 'Access violation' (2)
Not retrying...
=> ext2load virtio 0:1 0x1000000 /boot/bzImage
 <2, 0, 1024>
 <4, 0, 32>
 <488, 256, 128>
 <1448, 0, 8>
 <1448, 8, 1>
 <1448, 12, 8>
 <1448, 20, 2>
 <1448, 24, 8>
 <1448, 32, 10>
 <1448, 44, 8>
 <1448, 52, 3>
 <1448, 56, 8>
 <1448, 64, 3>
 <1448, 68, 8>
 <1448, 76, 3>
 <1448, 80, 8>
 <1448, 88, 3>
 <1448, 92, 8>
 <1448, 100, 5>
 <1448, 108, 8>
 <1448, 116, 7>
 <1448, 124, 8>
 <1448, 132, 5>
 <1448, 140, 8>
 <1448, 148, 3>
 <1448, 152, 8>
 <1448, 160, 3>
 <1448, 164, 8>
 <1448, 172, 4>
 <1448, 176, 8>
 <1448, 184, 4>
 <1448, 188, 8>
 <1448, 196, 3>
 <1448, 200, 8>
 <1448, 208, 4>
 <1448, 212, 8>
 <1448, 220, 3>
 <1448, 224, 8>
 <1448, 232, 3>
 <1448, 236, 8>
 <1448, 244, 3>
 <1448, 248, 8>
 <1448, 256, 3>
 <1448, 260, 8>
 <1448, 268, 4>
 <4, 192, 32>
 <98310, 0, 128>
 <99270, 0, 8>
 <99270, 8, 1>
 <99270, 12, 8>
 <99270, 20, 2>
 <99270, 24, 8>
 <99270, 32, 7>
 <4, 192, 32>
 <98310, 256, 128>
 <1448, 0, 8>
 <1448, 8, 1>
 <1448, 12, 8>
 <1448, 20, 2>
 <1448, 24, 8>
 <1448, 32, 10>
 <1448, 44, 8>
 <1448, 52, 3>
 <1448, 56, 8>
 <1448, 64, 3>
 <1448, 68, 8>
 <1448, 76, 3>
 <1448, 80, 8>
 <1448, 88, 3>
 <1448, 92, 8>
 <1448, 100, 5>
 <1448, 108, 8>
 <1448, 116, 7>
 <1448, 124, 8>
 <1448, 132, 5>
 <1448, 140, 8>
 <1448, 148, 3>
 <1448, 152, 8>
 <1448, 160, 3>
 <1448, 164, 8>
 <1448, 172, 4>
 <1448, 176, 8>
 <1448, 184, 4>
 <1448, 188, 8>
 <1448, 196, 3>
 <1448, 200, 8>
 <1448, 208, 4>
 <1448, 212, 8>
 <1448, 220, 3>
 <1448, 224, 8>
 <1448, 232, 3>
 <1448, 236, 8>
 <1448, 244, 3>
 <1448, 248, 8>
 <1448, 256, 3>
 <1448, 260, 8>
 <1448, 268, 4>
 <4, 192, 32>
 <98310, 0, 128>
 <99270, 0, 8>
 <99270, 8, 1>
 <99270, 12, 8>
 <99270, 20, 2>
 <99270, 24, 8>
 <99270, 32, 7>
 <4, 192, 32>
 <98310, 256, 128>
 <99272, 0, 1024>
 <99330, 0, 16384>
 <10914, 0, 49152>
 <11074, 0, 65536>
 <11266, 0, 131072>
 <99274, 0, 1024>
 <99276, 0, 1024>
 <99278, 0, 1024>
 <99280, 0, 1024>
 <11778, 0, 786432>
 <99282, 0, 1024>
 <99284, 0, 1024>
 <99286, 0, 1024>
 <99288, 0, 1024>
 <25602, 0, 1048576>
 <99290, 0, 1024>
 <99292, 0, 1024>
 <99294, 0, 1024>
 <99296, 0, 1024>
 <99298, 0, 1024>
 <99300, 0, 1024>
 <99302, 0, 1024>
 <99304, 0, 1024>
 <20482, 0, 2097152>
 <99306, 0, 1024>
 <99308, 0, 1024>
 <99310, 0, 1024>
 <28674, 0, 640672>
dev=virtio, devnr=0:1, path=/boot/bzImage, buffer=0000000001000000, size=49c6a0
Wrong FIT format: not a flattened device tree (err=-9)
- not remembering image
4834976 bytes read in 68 ms (67.8 MiB/s)
=> zboot 0x1000000
Valid Boot Flag
Setup Size = 0x00003800
Magic signature found
Using boot protocol version 2.0f
Linux kernel version 5.15.41 (mikhail@Prague) #1 SMP Wed Nov 6 10:12:54 CET 2024
Building boot_params at 0x00090000
Loading bzImage at address 100000 (4820640 bytes)

U-Boot SPL 2022.04 (Nov 05 2024 - 14:07:51 +0100)
notbr: returning err=-1
notbr: returning err=-1
notbr: returning err=-1
notbr: returning err=-1
notbr: returning err=-1
notbr: returning err=-1
Trying to boot from SPI
Jumping to 64-bit U-Boot: Note many features are missing
size=30, ptr=30, limit=1000: 1104e0
size=3c8, ptr=3f8, limit=1000: 110510
size=30, ptr=428, limit=1000: 1108d8
size=98, ptr=4c0, limit=1000: 110908
bind node chosen
Device 'chosen' has no compatible string
bind node aliases
Device 'aliases' has no compatible string
bind node memory
Device 'memory' has no compatible string
bind node serial
   - attempt to match compatible string 'ns16550'
   - found match at 'ns16550_serial': 'ns16550' matches 'ns16550'
size=30, ptr=4f0, limit=1000: 1109a0
size=98, ptr=588, limit=1000: 1109d0
size=28, ptr=5b0, limit=1000: 110a68
bind node keyboard
   - attempt to match compatible string 'intel,i8042-keyboard'
Skipping device pre-relocation
bind node reset
   - attempt to match compatible string 'x86,reset'
   - found match at 'x86_reset': 'x86,reset' matches 'x86,reset'
size=30, ptr=5e0, limit=1000: 110a90
size=98, ptr=678, limit=1000: 110ac0
size=8, ptr=680, limit=1000: 110b58
bind node rtc
   - attempt to match compatible string 'motorola,mc146818'
   - found match at 'motorola_mc146818': 'motorola,mc146818' matches 'motorola,mc146818'
size=30, ptr=6b0, limit=1000: 110b60
size=98, ptr=748, limit=1000: 110b90
bind node tsc-timer
   - attempt to match compatible string 'x86,tsc-timer'
   - found match at 'x86_tsc_timer': 'x86,tsc-timer' matches 'x86,tsc-timer'
size=30, ptr=778, limit=1000: 110c28
size=98, ptr=810, limit=1000: 110c58
bind node smbios
   - attempt to match compatible string 'u-boot,sysinfo-smbios'
Skipping device pre-relocation
bind node config
Device 'config' has no compatible string
bind node cpus
Device 'cpus' has no compatible string
bind node pci
   - attempt to match compatible string 'pci-x86'
   - found match at 'pci_x86': 'pci-x86' matches 'pci-x86'
size=30, ptr=840, limit=1000: 110cf0
size=98, ptr=8d8, limit=1000: 110d20
bind node pch@1,0
   - attempt to match compatible string 'intel,pch7'
   - found match at 'intel-pch7': 'intel,pch7' matches 'intel,pch7'
size=30, ptr=908, limit=1000: 110db8
size=98, ptr=9a0, limit=1000: 110de8
size=20, ptr=9c0, limit=1000: 110e80
bind node irq-router
   - attempt to match compatible string 'intel,irq-router'
No match for node 'irq-router'
bind node binman
Device 'binman' has no compatible string
size=8, ptr=9c8, limit=1000: 110ea0
size=20, ptr=9e8, limit=1000: 110ea8
size=18, ptr=a00, limit=1000: 110ec8


U-Boot 2022.04 (Nov 05 2024 - 14:07:51 +0100)

size=70, ptr=a70, limit=1000: 110ee0
size=1b8, ptr=c28, limit=1000: 110f50
notbr: returning err=-1
pre: returning err=-1
notbr: returning err=-1
pre: returning err=-1
pre: returning err=-1
pre: returning err=-1
size=30, ptr=c58, limit=1000: 111108
size=30, ptr=c88, limit=1000: 111138
size=98, ptr=d20, limit=1000: 111168
size=18, ptr=d38, limit=1000: 111200
bind node cpu@0
   - attempt to match compatible string 'cpu-qemu'
   - found match at 'cpu_qemu': 'cpu-qemu' matches 'cpu-qemu'
size=98, ptr=dd0, limit=1000: 111218
size=20, ptr=df0, limit=1000: 1112b0
CPU:   QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.5+
DRAM:  size=30, ptr=e20, limit=1000: 1112d0
size=8, ptr=e28, limit=1000: 111300
size=30, ptr=e58, limit=1000: 111308
1 GiB
bind node chosen
Device 'chosen' has no compatible string
bind node aliases
Device 'aliases' has no compatible string
bind node memory
Device 'memory' has no compatible string
bind node serial
   - attempt to match compatible string 'ns16550'
   - found match at 'ns16550_serial': 'ns16550' matches 'ns16550'
bind node keyboard
   - attempt to match compatible string 'intel,i8042-keyboard'
   - found match at 'i8042_kbd': 'intel,i8042-keyboard' matches 'intel,i8042-keyboard'
bind node reset
   - attempt to match compatible string 'x86,reset'
   - found match at 'x86_reset': 'x86,reset' matches 'x86,reset'
bind node rtc
   - attempt to match compatible string 'motorola,mc146818'
   - found match at 'motorola_mc146818': 'motorola,mc146818' matches 'motorola,mc146818'
bind node tsc-timer
   - attempt to match compatible string 'x86,tsc-timer'
   - found match at 'x86_tsc_timer': 'x86,tsc-timer' matches 'x86,tsc-timer'
bind node smbios
   - attempt to match compatible string 'u-boot,sysinfo-smbios'
   - found match at 'sysinfo_smbios': 'u-boot,sysinfo-smbios' matches 'u-boot,sysinfo-smbios'
bind node smbios
Device 'smbios' has no compatible string
bind node config
Device 'config' has no compatible string
bind node cpus
Device 'cpus' has no compatible string
bind node pci
   - attempt to match compatible string 'pci-x86'
   - found match at 'pci_x86': 'pci-x86' matches 'pci-x86'
bind node pch@1,0
   - attempt to match compatible string 'intel,pch7'
   - found match at 'intel-pch7': 'intel,pch7' matches 'intel,pch7'
bind node irq-router
   - attempt to match compatible string 'intel,irq-router'
No match for node 'irq-router'
bind node binman
Device 'binman' has no compatible string
binman: Selected image node 'rom'
Core:  10 devices, 10 uclasses, devicetree: separate
0
   - -1 'pci'
   - not found
vesa_video_bind: Frame buffer size fa0000
0
   - 0 'pci'
   - found
0
   - 0 'pci'
   - found
0
   - 0 'pci'
   - found
0
   - 0 'pci'
   - found
0
   - 0 'pci'
   - found
0
   - 0 'pci'
   - found
0
   - 0 'pci'
   - found
0
   - 0 'pci'
   - found
0
   - 0 'pci'
   - found
0
   - 0 'pci'
   - found
0
   - 0 'pci'
   - found
0
   - 0 'pci'
   - found
0
   - 0 'pci'
   - found
0
   - 0 'pci'
   - found
0
   - 0 'pci'
   - found
0
   - 0 'pci'
   - found
0
   - 0 'pci'
   - found
Loading Environment from nowhere... OK
0
   - 0 'vesa_video'
   - found
No x resolution: returning err=-6
returning err=-6
0
   - 0 'vesa_video'
   - found
Incorrect expansion ROM header signature 4daa
returning err=-22
Model: QEMU x86 (I440FX)
Net:   No ethernet found.
bind node cpu@0
   - attempt to match compatible string 'cpu-qemu'
   - found match at 'cpu_qemu': 'cpu-qemu' matches 'cpu-qemu'
smbios_version = 00000000000f00bf: '2022.04'
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
starting USB...
No working controllers found
USB is stopped. Please issue 'usb start' first.
scanning bus for devices...

Device 0: unknown device

Device 0: 1af4 VirtIO Block Device
            Type: Hard Disk
            Capacity: 61.0 MB = 0.0 GB (124928 x 512)
... is now current device
 <2, 0, 1024>
 <4, 0, 32>
 <488, 256, 128>
Scanning virtio 0:1...
 <2, 0, 1024>
 <4, 0, 32>
 <488, 256, 128>
 <1448, 0, 8>
 <1448, 8, 1>
 <1448, 12, 8>
 <1448, 20, 2>
 <1448, 24, 8>
 <1448, 32, 10>
 <1448, 44, 8>
 <1448, 52, 3>
 <1448, 56, 8>
 <1448, 64, 3>
 <1448, 68, 8>
 <1448, 76, 3>
 <1448, 80, 8>
 <1448, 88, 3>
 <1448, 92, 8>
 <1448, 100, 5>
 <1448, 108, 8>
 <1448, 116, 7>
 <1448, 124, 8>
 <1448, 132, 5>
 <1448, 140, 8>
 <1448, 148, 3>
 <1448, 152, 8>
 <1448, 160, 3>
 <1448, 164, 8>
 <1448, 172, 4>
 <1448, 176, 8>
 <1448, 184, 4>
 <1448, 188, 8>
 <1448, 196, 3>
 <1448, 200, 8>
 <1448, 208, 4>
 <1448, 212, 8>
 <1448, 220, 3>
 <1448, 224, 8>
 <1448, 232, 3>
 <1448, 236, 8>
 <1448, 244, 3>
 <1448, 248, 8>
 <1448, 256, 3>
 <1448, 260, 8>
 <1448, 268, 4>
 <2, 0, 1024>
 <4, 0, 32>
 <488, 256, 128>
 <1448, 0, 8>
 <1448, 8, 1>
 <1448, 12, 8>
 <1448, 20, 2>
 <1448, 24, 8>
 <1448, 32, 10>
 <1448, 44, 8>
 <1448, 52, 3>
 <1448, 56, 8>
 <1448, 64, 3>
 <1448, 68, 8>
 <1448, 76, 3>
 <1448, 80, 8>
 <1448, 88, 3>
 <1448, 92, 8>
 <1448, 100, 5>
 <1448, 108, 8>
 <1448, 116, 7>
 <1448, 124, 8>
 <1448, 132, 5>
 <1448, 140, 8>
 <1448, 148, 3>
 <1448, 152, 8>
 <1448, 160, 3>
 <1448, 164, 8>
 <1448, 172, 4>
 <1448, 176, 8>
 <1448, 184, 4>
 <1448, 188, 8>
 <1448, 196, 3>
 <1448, 200, 8>
 <1448, 208, 4>
 <1448, 212, 8>
 <1448, 220, 3>
 <1448, 224, 8>
 <1448, 232, 3>
 <1448, 236, 8>
 <1448, 244, 3>
 <1448, 248, 8>
 <1448, 256, 3>
 <1448, 260, 8>
 <1448, 268, 4>
 <2, 0, 1024>
 <4, 0, 32>
 <488, 256, 128>
 <1448, 0, 8>
 <1448, 8, 1>
 <1448, 12, 8>
 <1448, 20, 2>
 <1448, 24, 8>
 <1448, 32, 10>
 <1448, 44, 8>
 <1448, 52, 3>
 <1448, 56, 8>
 <1448, 64, 3>
 <1448, 68, 8>
 <1448, 76, 3>
 <1448, 80, 8>
 <1448, 88, 3>
 <1448, 92, 8>
 <1448, 100, 5>
 <1448, 108, 8>
 <1448, 116, 7>
 <1448, 124, 8>
 <1448, 132, 5>
 <1448, 140, 8>
 <1448, 148, 3>
 <1448, 152, 8>
 <1448, 160, 3>
 <1448, 164, 8>
 <1448, 172, 4>
 <1448, 176, 8>
 <1448, 184, 4>
 <1448, 188, 8>
 <1448, 196, 3>
 <1448, 200, 8>
 <1448, 208, 4>
 <1448, 212, 8>
 <1448, 220, 3>
 <1448, 224, 8>
 <1448, 232, 3>
 <1448, 236, 8>
 <1448, 244, 3>
 <1448, 248, 8>
 <1448, 256, 3>
 <1448, 260, 8>
 <1448, 268, 4>
 <2, 0, 1024>
 <4, 0, 32>
 <488, 256, 128>
 <1448, 0, 8>
 <1448, 8, 1>
 <1448, 12, 8>
 <1448, 20, 2>
 <1448, 24, 8>
 <1448, 32, 10>
 <1448, 44, 8>
 <1448, 52, 3>
 <1448, 56, 8>
 <1448, 64, 3>
 <1448, 68, 8>
 <1448, 76, 3>
 <1448, 80, 8>
 <1448, 88, 3>
 <1448, 92, 8>
 <1448, 100, 5>
 <1448, 108, 8>
 <1448, 116, 7>
 <1448, 124, 8>
 <1448, 132, 5>
 <1448, 140, 8>
 <1448, 148, 3>
 <1448, 152, 8>
 <1448, 160, 3>
 <1448, 164, 8>
 <1448, 172, 4>
 <1448, 176, 8>
 <1448, 184, 4>
 <1448, 188, 8>
 <1448, 196, 3>
 <1448, 200, 8>
 <1448, 208, 4>
 <1448, 212, 8>
 <1448, 220, 3>
 <1448, 224, 8>
 <1448, 232, 3>
 <1448, 236, 8>
 <1448, 244, 3>
 <1448, 248, 8>
 <1448, 256, 3>
 <1448, 260, 8>
 <1448, 268, 4>
 <4, 192, 32>
 <98310, 0, 128>
 <99270, 0, 8>
 <99270, 8, 1>
 <99270, 12, 8>
 <99270, 20, 2>
 <99270, 24, 8>
 <99270, 32, 7>
 <2, 0, 1024>
 <4, 0, 32>
 <488, 256, 128>
 <1448, 0, 8>
 <1448, 8, 1>
 <1448, 12, 8>
 <1448, 20, 2>
 <1448, 24, 8>
 <1448, 32, 10>
 <1448, 44, 8>
 <1448, 52, 3>
 <1448, 56, 8>
 <1448, 64, 3>
 <1448, 68, 8>
 <1448, 76, 3>
 <1448, 80, 8>
 <1448, 88, 3>
 <1448, 92, 8>
 <1448, 100, 5>
 <1448, 108, 8>
 <1448, 116, 7>
 <1448, 124, 8>
 <1448, 132, 5>
 <1448, 140, 8>
 <1448, 148, 3>
 <1448, 152, 8>
 <1448, 160, 3>
 <1448, 164, 8>
 <1448, 172, 4>
 <1448, 176, 8>
 <1448, 184, 4>
 <1448, 188, 8>
 <1448, 196, 3>
 <1448, 200, 8>
 <1448, 208, 4>
 <1448, 212, 8>
 <1448, 220, 3>
 <1448, 224, 8>
 <1448, 232, 3>
 <1448, 236, 8>
 <1448, 244, 3>
 <1448, 248, 8>
 <1448, 256, 3>
 <1448, 260, 8>
 <1448, 268, 4>
 <4, 192, 32>
 <98310, 0, 128>
 <99270, 0, 8>
 <99270, 8, 1>
 <99270, 12, 8>
 <99270, 20, 2>
 <99270, 24, 8>
 <99270, 32, 7>
 <2, 0, 1024>
 <4, 0, 32>
 <488, 256, 128>
 <1448, 0, 8>
 <1448, 8, 1>
 <1448, 12, 8>
 <1448, 20, 2>
 <1448, 24, 8>
 <1448, 32, 10>
 <1448, 44, 8>
 <1448, 52, 3>
 <1448, 56, 8>
 <1448, 64, 3>
 <1448, 68, 8>
 <1448, 76, 3>
 <1448, 80, 8>
 <1448, 88, 3>
 <1448, 92, 8>
 <1448, 100, 5>
 <1448, 108, 8>
 <1448, 116, 7>
 <1448, 124, 8>
 <1448, 132, 5>
 <1448, 140, 8>
 <1448, 148, 3>
 <1448, 152, 8>
 <1448, 160, 3>
 <1448, 164, 8>
 <1448, 172, 4>
 <1448, 176, 8>
 <1448, 184, 4>
 <1448, 188, 8>
 <1448, 196, 3>
 <1448, 200, 8>
 <1448, 208, 4>
 <1448, 212, 8>
 <1448, 220, 3>
 <1448, 224, 8>
 <1448, 232, 3>
 <1448, 236, 8>
 <1448, 244, 3>
 <1448, 248, 8>
 <1448, 256, 3>
 <1448, 260, 8>
 <1448, 268, 4>
 <4, 192, 32>
 <98310, 0, 128>
 <99270, 0, 8>
 <99270, 8, 1>
 <99270, 12, 8>
 <99270, 20, 2>
 <99270, 24, 8>
 <99270, 32, 7>
 <2, 0, 1024>
 <4, 0, 32>
 <488, 256, 128>
 <2, 0, 1024>
 <4, 0, 32>
 <488, 256, 128>
 <1448, 0, 8>
 <1448, 8, 1>
 <1448, 12, 8>
 <1448, 20, 2>
 <1448, 24, 8>
 <1448, 32, 10>
 <1448, 44, 8>
 <1448, 52, 3>
 <1448, 56, 8>
 <1448, 64, 3>
 <1448, 68, 8>
 <1448, 76, 3>
 <1448, 80, 8>
 <1448, 88, 3>
 <1448, 92, 8>
 <1448, 100, 5>
 <1448, 108, 8>
 <1448, 116, 7>
 <1448, 124, 8>
 <1448, 132, 5>
 <1448, 140, 8>
 <1448, 148, 3>
 <1448, 152, 8>
 <1448, 160, 3>
 <1448, 164, 8>
 <1448, 172, 4>
 <1448, 176, 8>
 <1448, 184, 4>
 <1448, 188, 8>
 <1448, 196, 3>
 <1448, 200, 8>
 <1448, 208, 4>
 <1448, 212, 8>
 <1448, 220, 3>
 <1448, 224, 8>
 <1448, 232, 3>
 <1448, 236, 8>
 <1448, 244, 3>
 <1448, 248, 8>
 <1448, 256, 3>
 <1448, 260, 8>
 <1448, 268, 4>
 <2, 0, 1024>
 <4, 0, 32>
 <488, 256, 128>
 <1448, 0, 8>
 <1448, 8, 1>
 <1448, 12, 8>
 <1448, 20, 2>
 <1448, 24, 8>
 <1448, 32, 10>
 <1448, 44, 8>
 <1448, 52, 3>
 <1448, 56, 8>
 <1448, 64, 3>
 <1448, 68, 8>
 <1448, 76, 3>
 <1448, 80, 8>
 <1448, 88, 3>
 <1448, 92, 8>
 <1448, 100, 5>
 <1448, 108, 8>
 <1448, 116, 7>
 <1448, 124, 8>
 <1448, 132, 5>
 <1448, 140, 8>
 <1448, 148, 3>
 <1448, 152, 8>
 <1448, 160, 3>
 <1448, 164, 8>
 <1448, 172, 4>
 <1448, 176, 8>
 <1448, 184, 4>
 <1448, 188, 8>
 <1448, 196, 3>
 <1448, 200, 8>
 <1448, 208, 4>
 <1448, 212, 8>
 <1448, 220, 3>
 <1448, 224, 8>
 <1448, 232, 3>
 <1448, 236, 8>
 <1448, 244, 3>
 <1448, 248, 8>
 <1448, 256, 3>
 <1448, 260, 8>
 <1448, 268, 4>
Scanning disk virtio-blk#1...
unhandled device class: virtio-pci.l#1 (virtio)
unhandled device class: pci (pci)
 <2, 0, 1024>
 <4, 0, 32>
 <488, 256, 128>
Found 2 disks
No EFI system partition
Initializing EFI driver framework
Adding EFI driver 'EFI block driver'
Incorrect expansion ROM header signature 4daa
returning err=-22
0
   - 0 'virtio-net#0'
   - found
0
   - 0 'virtio-net#0'
   - found
unhandled device class: virtio-pci.l#0 (virtio)
unhandled device class: pci (pci)
smbios_version = 000000003dcec03f: '2022.04'
BootOrder not defined
EFI boot manager: Cannot load any image
 <2, 0, 1024>
 <4, 0, 32>
 <488, 256, 128>
 <1448, 0, 8>
 <1448, 8, 1>
 <1448, 12, 8>
 <1448, 20, 2>
 <1448, 24, 8>
 <1448, 32, 10>
 <1448, 44, 8>
 <1448, 52, 3>
 <1448, 56, 8>
 <1448, 64, 3>
 <1448, 68, 8>
 <1448, 76, 3>
 <1448, 80, 8>
 <1448, 88, 3>
 <1448, 92, 8>
 <1448, 100, 5>
 <1448, 108, 8>
 <1448, 116, 7>
 <1448, 124, 8>
 <1448, 132, 5>
 <1448, 140, 8>
 <1448, 148, 3>
 <1448, 152, 8>
 <1448, 160, 3>
 <1448, 164, 8>
 <1448, 172, 4>
 <1448, 176, 8>
 <1448, 184, 4>
 <1448, 188, 8>
 <1448, 196, 3>
 <1448, 200, 8>
 <1448, 208, 4>
 <1448, 212, 8>
 <1448, 220, 3>
 <1448, 224, 8>
 <1448, 232, 3>
 <1448, 236, 8>
 <1448, 244, 3>
 <1448, 248, 8>
 <1448, 256, 3>
 <1448, 260, 8>
 <1448, 268, 4>

Reset IDE: Bus 0: OK Bus 1: OK 
  Device 0: not available
  Device 1: not available
  Device 2: Model: QEMU Firm: 2.5+ Ser#: QEMU DVD-ROM
            Type: Removable CD ROM
            Capacity: not available
  Device 3: not available

Device 0: unknown device
starting USB...
No working controllers found
0
   - 0 'virtio-net#0'
   - found
BOOTP broadcast 1
DHCP client bound to address 10.0.2.15 (2 ms)
Using virtio-net#0 device
TFTP from server 10.0.2.2; our IP address is 10.0.2.15
Filename 'boot.scr.uimg'.
Load address: 0x7000000
Loading: *
TFTP error: 'Access violation' (2)
Not retrying...
BOOTP broadcast 1
DHCP client bound to address 10.0.2.15 (1 ms)
Using virtio-net#0 device
TFTP from server 10.0.2.2; our IP address is 10.0.2.15
Filename 'boot.scr.uimg'.
Load address: 0x1000000
Loading: *
TFTP error: 'Access violation' (2)
Not retrying...

I've also gathered some information by adding -d int,pcall,cpu,cpu_reset,guest_errors -D qemu.log and there is a triple fault before cpu reset. The exception causing the triple fault:
check_exception old: 0xffffffff new 0xd
     1: v=0d e=0000 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0010:72b63af36fd82b54 pc=72b63af36fd82b54 SP=0018:000000000010e6b8 env->regs[R_EAX]=0000000000100000
RAX=0000000000100000 RBX=0000000000498ea0 RCX=0000000000000000 RDX=0000000000000000
RSI=000000000149c6a0 RDI=0000000000598ea0 RBP=0000000001000000 RSP=000000000010e6b8
R8 =0000000000000000 R9 =0000000000100000 R10=000000000010e46e R11=00000000000186a0
R12=0000000000000001 R13=000000000000020f R14=000000003eff6280 R15=0000000000003800
RIP=72b63af36fd82b54 RFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00af9a00 DPL=0 CS64 [-R-]
SS =0018 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0020 0000000000110118 00003fff 00809300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 0000000000000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000fffddc20 0000002f
IDT=     0000000000120000 000007ff
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000000080000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=0000000000000000 CCD=0000000000000000 CCO=SUBQ
EFER=0000000000000500
check_exception old: 0xd new 0xd
     2: v=08 e=0000 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0010:72b63af36fd82b54 pc=72b63af36fd82b54 SP=0018:000000000010e6b8 env->regs[R_EAX]=0000000000100000
RAX=0000000000100000 RBX=0000000000498ea0 RCX=0000000000000000 RDX=0000000000000000
RSI=000000000149c6a0 RDI=0000000000598ea0 RBP=0000000001000000 RSP=000000000010e6b8
R8 =0000000000000000 R9 =0000000000100000 R10=000000000010e46e R11=00000000000186a0
R12=0000000000000001 R13=000000000000020f R14=000000003eff6280 R15=0000000000003800
RIP=72b63af36fd82b54 RFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00af9a00 DPL=0 CS64 [-R-]
SS =0018 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0020 0000000000110118 00003fff 00809300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 0000000000000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000000fffddc20 0000002f
IDT=     0000000000120000 000007ff
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000000080000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=0000000000000000 CCD=0000000000000000 CCO=SUBQ
EFER=0000000000000500
check_exception old: 0x8 new 0xb


v2022.04 is rather old, can you try either v2024.10 or v2025.01-rc2? Thanks.
